# increment and decrement not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I am trying to create quantity field where user can increase and decrease the quantity. I am binding this field with `redux form`. There is an issue where if i keep on increasing it increases the number but when after increasing the number if i try to decrease the number it first increases and in second decrease it starts to decrease the number. When decreasing if the number is reached to the point of 1 then if i try to increase the number it will show 0 and then starts working in an expected way.

Here is the demo as well

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-lake-q3rw9

here is the source code

```
const QuantityField = ({ input, label, meta, inputCss, labelCss, ...rest }) => {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = React.useState(1);

  const handleIncrease = () => {
    setQuantity(quantity + 1);
    console.log("###################");
    rest.change(input.name, quantity);
    console.log("###################");
    console.log("input value", input.value);
  };

  const handleDecrease = () => {
    if (quantity > 0) {
      setQuantity(quantity - 1);
      rest.change(input.name, quantity);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <InputWrapper>
        {label && (
          <Label isActive={meta !== undefined && meta.active} css={labelCss}>
            {label}
          </Label>
        )}
        <TextInputWapper>
          <Augment onClick={() => handleIncrease()}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlus} style={{ color: "#fff" }} />
          </Augment>
          <TextInput
            css={inputCss}
            disabled
            isActive={meta !== undefined && meta.active}
            hasError={meta !== undefined && meta.touched && !!meta.error}
            {...input}
            {...rest}
          />
          <Augment onClick={() => handleDecrease()}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMinus} style={{ color: "#fff" }} />
          </Augment>
        </TextInputWapper>
        {meta !== undefined && meta.touched && !!meta.error && (
          <Error className="field-error">{meta.error}</Error>
        )}
      </InputWrapper>
    </>
  );
};

export default QuantityField;

const Augment = styled.span`
  background: #1ab394;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
```

Comment: maybe because in your     `<TextInput
            css={inputCss}
            disabled
            isActive={meta !== undefined && meta.active}
            hasError={meta !== undefined && meta.touched && !!meta.error}
            {...input}
            {...rest}
          />` The value that is being showed is input and not the state which is quantity

Comment: how can i adjust this with redux form state?

Comment: Where is this input being used?

Comment: sorry i did not understand you.

Comment: In your QuantityField component  if you change your `input.value = quantity` just before the return it solves your issue. But changing the value of props is a big no.

Comment: what's the recommended way? Can you help me by tweaking at the codesandbox, please?

Comment: If you want, I can share my code.

Comment: yes sure. I dont want anti pattern way(changing the props value). Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @Serenity checkout my answer and here is the working link https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-mestorf-r0qyt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are changing values just after `setQuantity` which is asynchronous so your next statement will not have the updated value instead you need to use `useEffect` to notify you the `quantity` value changes and then update/change your values

```
  const QuantityField = ({ input, label, meta, inputCss, labelCss, ...rest }) => {
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = React.useState(0);

  const handleIncrease = () => {
    setQuantity(quantity + 1);
    console.log("###################");
    // rest.change(input.name, quantity);
    console.log("###################");
    console.log("input value", input.value);
  };

  const handleDecrease = () => {
    if (quantity > 0) {
      setQuantity(quantity - 1);
      console.log("sss", quantity);
    }
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {          
      rest.change(input.name, parseInt(quantity,10));
  }, [quantity]);
```

here is the sandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-mestorf-r0qyt

Answer (score 0):

My Code is:-
**Actions**

```
import { MINUS_NUMBER, PLUS_NUMBER, RESET_NUMBER } from "./types";
export const minusAction = number => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: MINUS_NUMBER,
    payload: number
  });
};
export const plusAction = number => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: PLUS_NUMBER,
    payload: number
  });
};
export const resetAction = number => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: RESET_NUMBER,
    payload: number
  });
};
```

**Reducer**

```
const addNumber = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MINUS_NUMBER:
      return {
        ...state,
        number: action.payload - 1
      };
    case PLUS_NUMBER:
      return {
        ...state,
        number: action.payload + 1
      };
    case RESET_NUMBER:
      return {
        ...state,
        number: 0
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default addNumber;
```

**Root Reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import clickerReducer from "./clickerReducer";
export default combineReducers({
  clickerReducer
});
```

**component**

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { minusAction, plusAction, resetAction } from "../actions/clickerAction";
function App(props) {
  return (
    <div align="center" className="App">
      <h1>{props.number}</h1>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          props.minusAction(props.number);
        }}
      >
        -
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          props.resetAction(props.number);
        }}
      >
        Reset
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          props.plusAction(props.number);
        }}
      >
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  number: state.clickerReducer.number
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  minusAction,
  plusAction,
  resetAction
})(App);
```